# NHibernate querying on a string collection using Linq results in either error or empty collection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a problem with selecting a string collection and have reproduced it with the following small example.

Given the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [Post] (
    [Id]    INT     IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Name]  NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Post] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])
)
CREATE TABLE [Category] (
    [Id]    INT     IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [PostId]    INT NOT NULL,
    [Name]  NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Post] FOREIGN KEY ([PostId]) REFERENCES [Post]([Id])
)
INSERT INTO [Post] ([Name]) VALUES ('Post 1')
INSERT INTO [Category] ([PostId], [Name]) VALUES (1, 'Alpha')
```

And the code (I used LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    using (var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>().ConnectionString(@"Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=NhTest;"))
        .Mappings(x => {
            x.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(PostMap));
        })
        .BuildSessionFactory())
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        var post = session.Get<Post>(1);
        Debug.Assert(post.Categories.First() == "Alpha");

        try {
            var second = session.Query<Post>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                .Select(x => new {
                    x.Categories,
                    x.Name,
                })
                .Single();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.Fail(ex.ToString());
        }

        var third = session.Query<Post>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
            .Select(x => new {
                x.Categories,
                x.Name,
            })
            .ToList().First();

        Debug.Assert(third.Categories.Count() == 1, "Category count was " + third.Categories.Count());
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Categories { get; protected set; }
}

class PostMap : ClassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.Categories)
            .Table("Category")
            .Element("Name")
            .KeyColumn("PostId");
    }
}
```

The first assert passes and this, in my mind, validates my mapping of the categories onto the post.

The query in the try block throws an exception

```
'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object[]]
```

So I've changed it to the 3rd attempt you see in the code, calling `.ToList().First()`. This query does not throw any exception but the categories list is returned empty.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better mapping technique to use here? Or are there workarounds to get my query working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in NHibernate. It would try to get the class mapping data for the Enumerable type parameter. When projecting an Enumerable of a mapped class this works perfectly. In this instance, however, the Enumerable type parameter is string. String does not have a class map and so it was substituting a null constant in the query which then caused issues later on.

To further illustrate this, the SQL query for this example would be:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Id, p.Name FROM Post p LEFT JOIN Category c ON p.Id = c.PostId WHERE p.Id = 1
```

This would return data like so:

```
 c.Name | p.Id   | p.Name 
--------------------------
 Cat 1  | 1      | Post A
 Cat 2  | 1      | Post A
```

NHibernate would then, in memory, perform a group by operation, including null checks, to create a list of categories for each unique value of p.Id. The group by operation is performed using column indexes.

That is what should be happening. The bug was causing the results to be transformed, before the group by operation, into:

```
 NULL   | Cat 1  | 1      | Post A
 NULL   | Cat 2  | 1      | Post A
```

NHibernate was then filtering results where column 0 was null, meaning none of them survive.

The pull request containing the fix is here: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/262

Answer (score 1):

You can create `CategoryMap`, `Category` entity and change to:

```
public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; protected set; }
```

I'm presuming is a linq to nhibernate querying limitation.

Comment: I really wanted to avoid creating a new Category class as having a list of strings suits my domain better. I've also tried this with QueryOver and get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
var second = session.Query<Post>()
    .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
    .Select(x => new {
        x.Categories,
        x.Name,
    })
    .Single();
```

To `ToList().Single()` instead of `Single()`.

I've seen this issue before, the problem is that the query will return multiple rows that are then coerced into a single anonymous type. The query fails because the intermediate results contain multiple rows instead of a single row.

Comment: That's what I've done in the third query in my sample code but I get incorrect results.

Comment: Sorry for jumping on that without reading the whole thing. I created a nearly identical query and it returned the expected result. Have you profiled the SQL sent to the database? I see that you're using a local database, my guess is that you're not hitting the correct database.

Comment: I have profiled the query yes, and it does select the correct values. I'm stepping through the NH source code at the moment, it looks to be generating an incorrect client-side transform.

Comment: What was the nearly identical query that you created, out of interest, it might be worth me trying it in my environment.

Comment: It was the same form as yours but used Company and Addresses. I'm on NHibernate 3.3.3

Comment: Was Address a mapped class? The issue here was that I had a collection of non-mapped types.

Comment: Yes, Address was mapped. And I think you should map Category as well, but nice find!